# Select MySQL rows with timestamp older than 12 hours?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table `monitoring`, I want to select the content from the content `domain`.  But I only want to select it for rows where the timestamp on them is older than 12 hours and it should list the oldest entries first.

Here's what I've got so far and need help with:

```
SELECT domain FROM monitoring WHERE status = 'active' AND WHERE submit_time = '?????' ORDER BY '?????'
```

I know there are similar questions posted here about this.  However, the answers all seem dependent on the format of your time.  Here's how the time is listed in the database:

```
01-20-2016 23:12:13
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The ordering is separate and has no bearing on the current time (eg. `order by submit_time` [asc]) - date/time values get larger (are ascending) as time moves forward.

Comment: (If there is a 'format of the time' that makes a difference, it's likely not an appropriate field: yet a datetime field can be *displayed* differently, including in the manner shown. Go back to the table definition and have a peek to gain confidence about the column type.)

Comment: Vote to close dupes, guys. A little research effort helps too. [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT domain FROM monitoring WHERE status = 'active' AND submit_time <= '"' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-12 hours")) . "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

may we This will work for you.

```
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query="SELECT domain FROM monitoring WHERE status = 'active' AND TIMEDIFF('$date',submit_time)>'12:00:00' ORDER BY '?????'";
```